# How can I use $(this) in a function called by the onClick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the current state to selected when clicking on each link. I can do this by:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="places">
    <li class="selected">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myClick(0);">
          <span class="date">Saturday November 2, 2013</span>
          <span class="time">10am – 12pm</span>
          <span class="location">Western Sydney Parklands</span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myClick(1);">
          <span class="date">Saturday November 9, 2013</span>
          <span class="time">10am – 12pm</span>
          <span class="location">Bankstown High School</span>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myClick(2);">
          <span class="date">Tuesday November 12, 2013</span>
          <span class="time">9am – 11am</span>
          <span class="location">Greystanes Park</span>
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
        $('.places li a').click( function() {
           $('.places li').removeClass('selected');
           $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        });
    });
```

But this will double triggering onclick event on each link because the calling function `myClick()` is called to push data to map. Then I decided to implement these in the `myClick()` function:

```
function myClick( id ) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
    $('.places li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
}
```

The problem is that I cannot use `$(this)` to add class to its parent `li`.
See [what I have tried here](http://jsfiddle.net/vannkorn/hz7K2/).

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, that jsfiddle.net link didn't work. You need to hit 'save'.

Comment: Yes, Christian Ternus. I just updated. Pls see my updated

Comment: Why are you using onclick rather than adding the event handler with jQuery? You can still use myClick - just pass it as the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are saying, you can't use jQuery click handler, pass the clicked anchor element reference to `myClick` using `onclick="myClick(0, this);"`

```
<li class="selected">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myClick(0, this);">
      <span class="date">Saturday November 2, 2013</span>
      <span class="time">10am – 12pm</span>
      <span class="location">Western Sydney Parklands</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

then

```
function myClick( id, el ) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
    $('.places li').removeClass('selected');
    $(el).parent().addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: +1, if you're stuck using an inline event this is the correct way.

Comment: agreed, if the `onclick` is a requirement

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the numbers are in fact indices, i.e. `0` is the first anchor, `1` is the second, etc.; in that case you can use this code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $places = $('.places li a'),
    $selection;

    $places.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($selection) {
            $selection.removeClass('selected');
        }

        $selection = $(this).parent()
            .addClass('selected');

        myClick($places.index(this));
    });
});
```

The remaining HTML would be something like this:

```
<li class="selected">
   <a href="#">
      <span class="date">Saturday November 2, 2013</span>
      <span class="time">10am – 12pm</span>
      <span class="location">Western Sydney Parklands</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

See how clean that is? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Change this code

```
$(this)
```

to

```
$(this.event.srcElement).parent().parent() //span is clicked, go to anchor then go to li
```

Comment: I edited my answer. I'm getting an error in your fiddle "myClick  is undefined" so I tried this solution in my desktop

Comment: Yes, the fiddle link shows error. Define myClick() before you call it.

Comment: No, a is clicked not the span one. I also tried yours and does not work

Comment: The click event is actually done on the span element which is inside the anchor element and also which is inside the li element. For some reason I am getting a "myClick is undefined error" in JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without using the `onclick` since you are already using jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/hz7K2/11/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var anchors = $('.places li a'),
        items = $('.places li');

    anchors.click( function() {
        var item = $(this).parent();
        items.removeClass('selected');
        item.addClass('selected');

        //using the jQuery index() method will get you the id of the LI that was 
        //clicked, assuming it is alway 0-based & sequential
        myClick( items.index(item) );
    });
});

function myClick( id ){
 alert('you clicked item '+id);   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you change the markup?

```
<li id="item2">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-item="2" onclick="myClick(2);">
          <span class="date">Tuesday November 12, 2013</span>
          <span class="time">9am – 11am</span>
          <span class="location">Greystanes Park</span>
       </a>
    </li>



$('a').click(function(){
 var clickedId = $(this).attr('data-item'); //use data attribute
 $('#item' + clickedId).addClass('selected');
})
```

Comment: Actually yes, but I am not allowed to used click function. I have to use only the myClick() function to perform this.

Comment: -1 this is a bad solution. It stores more logic in the HTML, if you just want the row number in the list you can use .eq and .index . Using sequential ifs always indicates unfamiliarity with SoC and arrays.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum HTML attributes are not 'logic'. Parsing the DOM is expensive. Selecting by #id is the BEST way to perform selections using jQuery.

Comment: @tepkenvannkorn read my above. You absolutely want to select by id whenever you can using jQuery. Its the most efficient selector. Since you are already passing the id to myClick() then just do $('#item' + clickedId).addClass('selected'); within that function.

Comment: @Nick even of we disregard that querying the dom in this case (or 1000 times for that matter) is really really not expensive. That said, this is not what I was suggesting at all. Query the DOM once and have an array of objects backing your HTML instead of having to store that logic in the HTML. JavaScript has variables that do this sort of thing well :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum How do you know it's not expensive? This could be a mobile application for all we know.It's a bad habit and bad practice. The HTML spec provides attributes such as ID for a reason. That reason is CSS selection. Adding id attribute to HTML elements is not adding 'logic' to markup. You either add to your markup or add to your script. Something becomes more verbose.

Comment: @Nick Stop spreading FUD. Even IE6 on a Pentium 3 on a VM can still do 10K id selections per second (and it [just did](http://i.imgur.com/OsWILge.png), the problem is when looping selection heaviliy or doing so in nested constructs. The HTML spec provides attributes such as ID mainly for fragment identifiers (have you actually _read_ the spec?) They do make sense when selection sometimes but not when the real solution is a backing JS `Array` for your logic. Adding sequential ids to elements shows lack of fundamental understanding of both how to structure GUI and the DOM API.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes. I've read most the spec. Right from W3C "The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific id." You can argue about markup semantics all day.  Which, by the way, is purely subjective considering it's 100% valid HTML. What is not subjective is a. this is a jQuery question and b. selecting by element id in jQuery is the most efficient method. Plenty of bench tests out there to prove that.

Comment: You don't need an explicit relationship from a child to its parent. And no, the tiny difference in performance (which could go either way, if only because you're concatenating strings here) does not balance out the reduced developer performance. Also, I claim that `.parent()` is much faster than selection by ID.

Comment: Not only is your approach worse stylewise, it's also much slower. Credit goes to Benjamin for the perf: http://jsperf.com/select-by-id-vs-parent

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum LMAO. I did. Nothing gets by this guy. It was the first to come up on Google and being late I didn't feel like locating the attribute def in the spec (and that statement was so self serving). Are you calling W3C schools a liar?! How dare you sir! I'll look at your bench because if, indeed, you are right about parent() being faster than $('#someid') in this case.. I am happy to concede and ride away into the sunset.